# Prestashop BlockTopMenu Drop Down Issue

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a problem with the dropdown property of BlockTopMenu on Prestashop v1.6.0.11

I have 4 main categories in my menu and they have subcategories.
In my website, menu dropdown works well in the homepage
and all categories except "brands", "new" and "sale".

These are problematic categories -you can check here-

```
http://goo.gl/vmtm8C #MainCategory (brands)
http://goo.gl/qHGvup #MainCategory (new)
http://goo.gl/8fzIx7 #MainCategory (sale)
```

Some working categories -you can check here-

```
http://goo.gl/UC1tdd #HomePage
http://goo.gl/zkHyY6 #MainCategory (men)
http://goo.gl/8leaZm #SubCategory (men / under the "new" category)
```

I cannot explain the problem, could you help me to understand it and solve it?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely because you "deleted" or "disabled" blocklayered block, and the `blocklayered.js` is still included in the header, trying to execute it's code, but there is no content to work with.

Look at your JS console. You can trace back the error @`blocklayered.js` to

```
Line 248 from = formatCurrency($('#layered_'+slider['type']+'_slider').slider('values', 0), slider['format'], slider['unit']);
```

This error stops any further code from executing (possibly the menu code) too.

So, fix this error first or uninstall the blocklayered module and see what happens then